# Sort List with Numbers

Tags: list, sorting, vim, numbers, numeric

This is List `L`:

```
['25', '2', '15', '4', '81', '43']
```

This is the output when I use the command `sort(L)`

```
['15', '2', '25', '4', '43', '81']
```

This is what I want as output:

```
['2', '4', '15', '25', '43', '81']
```

Is there a command to sort numbers in a list as `%sort n` does in commandline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is explained in the [documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#sort%28%29). You need to define a function to do the comparison between list entries. The function should return 0 if its arguments are equal, 1 if the the first argument is larger than the second, and -1 if the second argument is larger than the first.

```
function! MyCompare(i1, i2)
    return a:i1 == a:i2 ? 0 : a:i1 > a:i2 ? 1 : -1
endfunction
```

Then you can call sort() using your new function as the second argument. Hence:

```
let list = ['25', '2', '15', '4', '81', '43']
echo sort( list, 'MyCompare' )
```

will echo

```
[2, 4, 15, 25, 43, 81]
```

as expected.

Comment: Prince Goulash, never understood this in `h: sort()`. Btw I use this function from inside another function in menu.vim. `function! <sid>MyCompare ... endfunction`. When I call this function: `let s:mylist = sort(s:mylist, '<SID>MyCompare')` it doesn't find the function. Without <SID> neither. What did I wrong?

Comment: Found the solution! The other function in the documentation works fine. Tnx.